# where is the Ansible's library in Mac

Tags: ios, ansible

I know we can find ansible's library where is /usr/share/ansible when we use linux,we also write the path in our ansible.cfg.But we can find it in Mac OS by this way,so I just want to know where is the library in Mac and how to write in ansible.cfg

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? do you want to know how to set/override defaults in ansible.cfg?

Answer (score 4):

On a mac there are various ways to install ansible.
i.e. Homebrew

```
brew install ansible
```

will put ansible in /usr/local/Cellar

```
pip install
```

allows you to find the location with

```
pip show ansible
```

and the source installation will put it wherever you define.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source

We'd need more info to answer your question